# Simple JavaScript Password protection not working on mobile platform

Tags: javascript, mobile, browser

```
<script language="JavaScript"> 
var password; 
var pass1="apple"; 
password=prompt('Password?',' '); 
if (password!=pass1) {window.location="WRONG.html";}
</script>
```

This code works fine on desktop chrome, firefox, safari, ect.  But when I load the page in a mobile browser such as mobile chrome or mobile safari, I am redirected towards "wrong.html" every time.  What am I missing?

Comment: Seriously ? Fixing that wouldn't make it much better. That's zero security there.

Comment: Sounds like maybe `prompt` is not implemented?

Comment: Basically, since JavaScript can be bypassed (or completely modified) by the client, it is a highly insecure way to validate users.

Comment: use input box instead (password input box) and then compare in javascript. and @ChrisForrence is right... javascript is insecure

Comment: Print both passwords before the redirect and see what the

Comment: It's funny how people mention javascript is insecure while the password is visible in plain text same as the (secured) URL. ;-)

Comment: @Bart - Well, that too! In other news, I'd see what server-side languages are available for you, auby1885, so that you can better secure your site.

Comment: Thanks Psy.  Works now.  Does anyone have a suggestion for a very simple and more secure alternative?  Thanks!

Comment: `language="JavaScript"`...Haven't seen that one in a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the space out of the second argument for prompt().  For some reason the mobile platform(s) are retaining it and that extra space is making the comparison always evaluate false.  Also, this is a pretty bad security scheme.  Just sayin'.

```
<script language="JavaScript"> 
var password; 
var pass1="apple"; 
password=prompt('Password?',''); 
if (password!=pass1) {window.location="WRONG.html";}
</script>
```

Comment: Hey, that works!  Do you have a suggestion for a very simple alternative?  Thanks!

Comment: I would go with a server side language as ChrisForrence suggested.  PHP, .NET, c#, perl -- any of these will do.  It all depends on your host and what they can provide.  JavaScript is world readable by anyone so they can just 'view source' to see what the password is.  With a server side language you can write virtually the same logic and have the password hidden; though this is still a bad security scheme it will still be better and you will learn from it.  Good luck!